# HDF error when atempting to read netCDF file using netCDF4 module in python

Tags: netcdf4

When I try to open a netcdf4 file containing tropomi data of the ESA copernicus mission, I run into the following error.

```
[Errno -101] NetCDF: HDF error: b'5P_NRTI_L2__CO_____20190505T104819_20190505T105319_08073_01_010301_20190505T124936.nc'
```

the code that I use is simply

```
import netCDF4
rootgrp = netCDF4.Dataset(5P_NRTI_L2__CO_____20190505T104819_20190505T105319_08073_01_010301_20190505T124936.nc, "r",format="NETCDF4")
```

If i re-install netCDF4 or shutdown my computer a few times it succeeds in reading the file again (though this trick does not always work). But it's just a matter of time before it starts failing again. Does anyone have any idea what causes this problem? I work under Ubuntu 18.

Comment: Do you close the file properly after opening it?

Comment: Yes, the error also persists after restarting my computer. So it is probably not that.

Answer (score 1):

python-netCDF4 might be buggy, here is an example with another library which normally works for me (https://github.com/shoyer/h5netcdf):

```
import h5netcdf.legacyapi as netCDF4

with netCDF4.Dataset('mydata.nc', 'w') as ds:
   ...
```

Comment: This works. If it breaks down over time in the same way as the netCDF4 package I will report back.